# SharePoint: Make a list field Required programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I have a list and one of the list field is of managed meta data field type.It has to be a required field on the list.I would not set the Required attribute to true in the XML file, as other lists in the project use it as a optional field.Searched many articles, none of them helped .

Note: Field.Required=true;
      Field.Update();
Doesn't make the field as required field
Field is not part of content type

Any ideas on this are appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is the field a part of a contenttype? In that case you might want to get a reference to the fieldlink and set that as required:

```
var myField = list.Fields["MyFieldName"];
var ct = list.Contenttypes["MyContentType"];

var fieldLink = ct.FieldLinks[myField];
fieldLink.Required = true;
ct.Update();
```

Comment: This worked for me when setting the "Location" field of a calendar/events list to be required, while no other method I tried worked. Thanks!

Comment: I needed to set require on the content type itself (not attached to a list). Using FieldLinks worked there too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`

```
SPField field = list.Fields["MyField"]; 
field.Required= true;
field.Update();
list.Update();
```

`

Comment: This worked for me when setting the "Title" field to be non-mandatory when creating a new list.

Answer (score -2):

Use `sharepoint designer`, select the list, a listing of columns will be displayed.

Double click the column and within the Column Editor popup uncheck "`Allow blank Values?`".  Save and test...field should now be mandatory.

Comment: That is not programmatically.